# Multinational Coefficient Difficulty

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

Given
$$\left( 2x + xy - z + \frac{1}{xyz} \right) ^{10}$$

it is asked to caltulate the coeficient of
$$ x^6 y^5 z$$

I tried to simplify the formula to only have 3 "parcels" but with no success. the sum of the exponential of $x$, $y$ and $z$ should be $10$ which is not true. Am i missing any rule here?

Comment: Hint: Do you know the formula for the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)?

Comment: Yes. But how can i do it when there are 3 variables but 4 "parcels". The question here is how do i get rid of that 1/xyz

Comment: Factor out the $xyz$, and look for the coefficient of $x^{16}y^{15}z^{11}$ in the expansion of the numerator.

Comment: And what can you deduce from the fact that the power in $x$ is one higher than the power of $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are looking for $a, b, c, d$ such that $x^a+(xy)^b +z^c+(\frac{1}{xyz})^d = x^6 y^5 z$, where some conditions must be met:

$a+b+c+d=10$, $a+b-d=6$, $b-d=5$ and $c-d=1$.

This is a system of $4$ linear equations with $4$ variables which can be solved leading to $(a,b,c,d)=(1,6,2,1)$.

So you are inspecting the term

$$
\frac{10!}{1!6!2!1!}(2x)^1(xy)^6(-z)^2(\frac{1}{xyz})^1 = 2520\cdot2^1(-1)^2x^6y^5z = 5040\cdot x^6y^5z
$$

Comment: Thank you! Now i understand.